# Former Adventurer achievement requirements

Tags: achievements, tomb-raider-2013

I'm attempting the Former Adventurer achievement and something is not clear to me

> **Incapacitate 25 enemies with dodge counter.**

To be able to dodge counter, you have to unlock the skill **Dodge Counter**:

> After dodging an enemy, stab them in the knee with an arrow to cripple them and leave them vulnerable to killing blow.

But there are also the skills **Dodge Kill**

> *Dodge Counter required.* Skillfully dodge lightly armored opponents and then strike them at close range to kill them instantly.

and **Dodge Kill Mastery**

> *Dodge Kill required.* Striking after dodging becomes even more deadly, allowing you to kill almost any enemy.

Does this mean I **must not** unlock the Dodge Kill skills, because I wouldn't incapacitate enemies anymore? This is how I would expect it, but so far it hasn't unlocked with the two latter skills still locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [playstationtrophies.org](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/tomb-raider-9/trophy/61118-Former-Adventurer.html):

> Also try to earn it before you learn Dodge Kill skill, so you don't accidentally kill the enemy instead of incapacitating him.

So basically, learning **Dodge Kill** is *not* recommended until you have the achievement.

You can still earn the achievement after learning it, however:

> You can do it with the "Dodge/Kill" skill also. Watch the circle when it appears. If you press Triangle when it is BETWEEN the outer edge and the inner symbol, you will get an "incapacitate", but if you wait for the circle to fill up and highlight the Triangle symbol, you get the "dodge/kill".